# How can i store images in an array and with a for loop print them? PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I try to print images with a for loop but the images dont load.

```
<?php
$imagenes = array('1.png', '2.jpg', '3.png', '4.jpg','IMG_0105.JPG');
 ?>
```

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <?php
              for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
              echo '<img src = \"$imagenes[$i]\"  width = \'100px\' height = \'100px\';>';
              }
         ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The images are in the same folder as the .php file

Comment: `echo "<img src='$imagenes[$i]'  width='100px' height='100px'>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Added additional solutions based on answer from @nik

This will never work because variables are not evaluated inside of single quoted strings.

Make sure that your use a string inside double quotes. Or use string concatenation to build the HTML tag. Also, you image tag has a semicolon inside of it that might break the tag.

So you can do this ...

```php
echo "<img src=\"{$imagenes[$i]}\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\">";
```

or

```php
echo "<img src=\"" . $imagenes[$i] . "\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\">";
```

or

```php
<img src="<?= $imagenes[$i]; ?>" width="100px" height="100px">
```

or

```php
<img src="<?php echo $imagenes[$i]; ?>" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach for this. And for concatinate string with var - use . (dot)

```
       <?php
             foreach ($imagenes as $image) {
                echo '<img src = "'.$image.'"  width = "100px" height = "100px">';
             }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would make it simplier:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <?php foreach ($imagenes as $url) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" width="100px" height="100px">
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its the way you're escaping the characters, you can just use concatenation on `$images`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                echo '<img src = '.$imagenes[$i].' width="100px" height ="100px";>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```